# How can I manage to avoid the underline in a text-decoration: none

Tags: web-part, script

I am trying to solve the problem with  the underline in a text-decoration: none.
This is the script I have:

p { padding: 5px 0; }
 

a:link { text-decoration: none; }

a:visited { text-decoration: none; }

a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

a:active { text-decoration: none; }

But the underline is still there. Even if I try to insert !important. It is still there. Need some help!

Comment: Check the F12 console which style is applied. Most likely another CSS declaration gets a **higher CSS Specificity** (use google) and overrules your declaration. Note that ``!important`` was created for people who do understand CSS and is only used by people who do not understand CSS

Answer (score 0):

Should be working. In your question you use, "script", of course this should be inside the style tags.
Also see: [This,](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi7pva_76jSAhXIRCYKHTMGDWkQFggwMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10853881%2Fhow-to-remove-underline-from-a-link-in-html&usg=AFQjCNFmuc2OMVA7fYDg-I2Bo0Y9Vo0acQ&sig2=rU6ztmrNKae3RQcicXhiBw&bvm=bv.148073327,d.eWE/)
[And this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi7pva_76jSAhXIRCYKHTMGDWkQFggwMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10853881%2Fhow-to-remove-underline-from-a-link-in-html&usg=AFQjCNFmuc2OMVA7fYDg-I2Bo0Y9Vo0acQ&sig2=rU6ztmrNKae3RQcicXhiBw&bvm=bv.148073327,d.eWE)